# Meaning of ' .. ' vs ' . ' in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone explain what's the difference between

```dart
create: (context) => AppBloc()..add(event: AppStarted())),
```

vs

```dart
create: (context) => AppBloc().add(event: AppStarted())),
```

The only difference is the `..`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very simple words... the .. (Cascade Notation) is used chain functions together.

Example:

```
// with cascade notation:
querySelector('#confirm') // Get an object.
  ..text = 'Confirm' // Use its members.
  ..classes.add('important')
  ..onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'))

// without cascade notation
var button = querySelector('#confirm');
button.text = 'Confirm';
button.classes.add('important');
button.onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

Comment: I'd say it even simpler than that.  The result of a.b is the return value of b.  The result of a..b is a, after calling a.b and discarding its result.